# Excel Formula - Count Unique Projects but Exclude 'Admin'

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am looking for some Excel related help for a formula which I've not been able to figure out myself.

I have a sample list of data in range A1:B7 - Column A is a list of names (e.g. John, Jane, etc) and column B is a list of project codes (e.g. ABC, ABD, Admin, etc), just like this:

```
   A      B
  John   ABC
  Jane   ABD
  John   Admin
  Jane   ABC
  Mike   ABD
  John   ABC
  Jane   Admin
```

I want to **count the number of unique projects** that John and Jane have each worked on but **exclude** the *Admin* project.

For example, John has worked twice on project *ABC*' and *Admin*, therefore the unique project count for John would be **1**.

Jane has worked on projects *ABC*, *ABD* and *Admin*, therefore the unique project count for Jane would be **2**.

I've tried all various combinations of sumifs, countifs and pivot tables but not managed to count the unique projects with the exclusion of *Admin*.

Comment: Welcome to Super User MDunn. Edit the question or post a comment with a link to the image[s] and someone will edit them in for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it if you have the table sorted by name. I figure you could do that.

`=SUM(1/COUNTIF(B1:B4;B1:B4))-IF(COUNTIF(B1:B4;"=Admin")>0;1;0)`

You might need to replace `;` with `,` in formula, if your version of excel differs from mine. Make sure to cofirm this formula by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, not just `ENTER`. This counts number of unique entries for `B1:B4`, excluding Admin. Assuming `B1:B4` are only John's project, this would be the number for John.

You probably could do it without sorting your table, but I couldn't figure out how. The links below might help.

I used the following information: here is the [link](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-unique-values.html) explaining how to count number of unique values in a column. It uses something called array functions. You can read about them [here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

UPD: Also see the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476487/exclude-cell-value-from-rank-range-based-on-value-in-another-cell) question. It discusses how to exclude cell from the range, which should be helpful. You would expand the `B1:B4` to the whole column and then exclude those cells which don't have John in the adjacent cell. I couldn't try it out in my Excel 2003.

Comment: You surely mean B1:B7 instead of B1:B4 ? :) +1 from me

Comment: @duDE no, I mean B1:B4 in the table where those are cells with John's projects. I couldn't figure out how to get John's projects other than have the table sorted and then have B1:B4 for John, B5:B7 for jane, etc.

Comment: This is one possible solution but not really that workable when the spreadsheet has large amounts of data and various 'names'. I did find a workaround using an IF statement and SUMPRODUCT then drove a pivot from the result. Thanks for your input though :)

Comment: @MDunn Glad you found my answer useful. Care to post your solution as an update to your question or as an answer?